# What tools i need to show the following?

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces

Let $X,Y$ be NLS. Let $T: X\rightarrow Y$ be a linear map. Prove that $T$ is continuous iff it is continuous at $0\in$X.

Honestly I don't understand this question if $T$ is continuous on $X$ then it is continuous at each point of $X$ and since $0\in X$ then it is continuous at $0$. What does this question mean? What tools do I need to know to prove this. I already know that the NLS $\Vert$ $\Vert$ is continuous on $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: "iff" stands for "if and only if". Therefore, the question is asking you to prove the following two facts: 1) if $T$ is continuous, then it is continuous at $0$; 2) if $T$ is continuous at $0$, then it is continuous.

Comment: For continuity you need a metric,  so what is the metric inferred?

Comment: @dmtri Presumably NLS stand for Normed vector (Linear) Space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is linearity: Given $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $\|Tz\|=\|Tz-T0\|<\epsilon$ whenver $\|z-0\|<\delta$. Hence $\|Tx-Ty\|=\|T(x-y)\|<\epsilon$  whenever $\|x-y\|<\delta$. And this proves continuity, in fact uniform continuity, of $T$.